# How to check where is the control template defined which gets applied to a control

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have a used a control, say ListView, in my custom control. When i run my application i could see that ListView is not rendered in a different way. I suspect that somewhere a control template is defined for listview/listviewitem which resulted in this behavior. I checked the Template property of listview at runtime where i could see childitems are different.

Is there a way to find out that where is this template defined? I understand this sounds like a naive question and i should go thru all the resources and see where i could be present. I tried that but bcoz of complexity/number of the resource items i could not find anything useful.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have sources of all resources? If so, Search for `pe="ListView"` (for Silverlight and WPF) and for `pe="{x:Type ListView}"` (for WPF only). This will look for all styles/Templates with TargetType of list view. Then see if you have a style without a key.

Comment: I have tried this with all the resources known to me. but there is quite a hierarchy of resources, so might be i have not checked all the resources